# Auto-Reload of the page in Swing during Runtime

Tags: java, swing

By how many ways can we do a auto-reload of the page in Swing? Suppose, after 'n' time interval I want to perform some action, then how can be that achieved? And which can be the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SwingTimer` for that purpose. Read more in [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)